# AWS Athena query struct property in array

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena, presto

I have json files in S3 bucket generated by AWS Textract service and I'm using Athena to query data from those files. Every file has the same structure and I created a table in Athena where I have column "blocks" that is array of struct:

```
  "blocks": [{
      "BlockType": "LINE",
      "Id": "12345",
      "Text": "Text from document",
      "Confidence": 98.7022933959961,
      "Page": "1",
      "SourceLanguage": "de",
      "TargetLanguage": "en",
    },
    ...100+ blocks]
```

How can I query just for the "Text" property from every block that has one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what exactly is stored in the column in question? Json array?

Comment: @GuruStron regular array is stored under that column

Comment: Can you please show an example of data? What is returned by `select block_column from ...`?

Comment: @GuruStron It has returned hundreds of blocks - I will show 1 blocks:

`[{blocktype=PARAGRAPH, Id=d93589de-2590-4919-87a5-c10aca6ed524, page=1, text=Biologistes médicaux, confidence=99.29962158203125, sourcelanguage=fr, targetlanguage=en}]`

Comment: can you please add result of `select typeof(block_column) ...` but it seems that you will need either `unnest` or `transform`+`filter` and some `ROW` handling

Comment: @GuruStron here is the result of that query:
`array(row(blocktype varchar, page integer, text varchar, confidence double, sourcelanguage varchar, targetlanguage varchar))`

Comment: And final question - what is desired output? row per block entry in array? or array of nin-null texts?

Comment: The desired output would be: `[{text=Biologistes médicaux}, {text=example text}, ...]` and probably I would add ID beside text property.

Answer (score 1):

I have defined a table with exact schema of yours using sample JSON provided.

```
_col0
#   
array(row(blocktype varchar, id varchar, text varchar, confidence double, page varchar, sourcelanguage varchar, targetlanguage varchar))
```

I have used unnest operator to flatten the array of blocks and fetch the Text column from it using below query:

```
select block.text from <table-name> CROSS JOIN UNNEST(blocks) as t(block)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like column stores array of rows, so you can process it as one ([array functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#transform)):

```sql
select transform(
     filter(block_column, t -> t.text is not null), 
     r => cast(row(r.text) as row(text varchar))) texts
from table
```